# Java script number format change

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've number i.e. 12345678 and I want to change it to the following format
[12,34,56,78]. How can I do that?

Comment: please make an attempt and share it before asking for help

Comment: Can you show us something you have tried already (some code)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `match`

```js
var str = '12345678';
console.log(str.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(Number));
```